# Is there anyway to make simpleXML work on web host

Tags: php, simplexml, file-get-contents

```
    <?php
$twitter_url = 'http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/ishrikrishna.xml?count=1';

$buffer = file_get_contents($twitter_url);

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($buffer);

$status = $xml -> status;

$tweet =  $status -> text;

echo $tweet;

?>
```

I used this code to fetch tweets and it works successfully on localhost but not on my webhost, I tried this script on two webhosting services.

The problem i've noticed is that functions like file_get_contents(), simplexml_load_file() failed to fetch data from xml file(ex. rss files) stored on another server.

Comment: Looks like some kind of configuration issue on the hosting servers. There maybe some kind of restriction on accessing methods that are related to file operation.

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting ?

Comment: Blank webpage on webhost, but localhost retrieve tweet successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this means you have the fopen URL wrappers turned off.  See http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen  You will probably not be able to turn these on if you are using a shared web server.

You may be able to use cURL to fetch remote pages instead:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/ishrikrishna.xml?count=1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$buffer = curl_exec($ch);
```

This will only work you have the cURL extension installed and enabled on your webhost.

See the PHP cURL documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

**Edit:** corrected curl_setopt call

Comment: Curl also not works, Is there anyway to install and use our own php version on webpages or is there any methode to enable extentions like simplexml via .htaccess file.

Comment: No, you can only enable the fopen wrappers in php.ini, and I expect a webhost that has them turned off will not allow you to enable them.  It is perfectly possible that you do not have the ability to load remote files from your webhost.  I'd advise you to contact your webhost and check whether they have indeed got allow_url_fopen turned off.

Comment: Okay, I will contact them, Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXML is new in PHP 5. I think almost all webhosts have PHP 5 installed, but in case your host is still using PHP 4 that may be the reason your script isn't working.